# how to implement search on property in list (Collection)

Tags: java, list, search, comparator

I want to implement search on property of objects which are in list.

```
class Test
{
    int id;
    int name;
    int address;

    //Setter and getter method of properties
}

public List<Test> searchData(String serachText, String propertyName)
{
    //Write code to search data from list
}
```

**Input param:**

```
searchData("val1", "name");
searchData("val2", ("address");
```

I want to go with `Collections.binarySearch` but how to make `dynamic comparator` search that I don't know.

what is right way to implement such function?

Is it possible to implement it using `Collections.binarySearch` or any other good way with good quality of code with **better performance**?

**Edit**

```
public List<Test> searchData(String serachText, String propertyName)
{
List<Test> finalSearch=new ArrayList<Test>();
//Write code to search data
for(Test test:testList)
{
  if(propertyName.equals("name"))
{
    if(serachText.equals(test.getName())
    {
       finalSearch.add(test);
     }
///Same code for others
}
}
}
```

Comment: First write a search using a plain old loop.  Then study what you wrote and figure out what parts comprise the comparator.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? you mean looping the list and according to property compare search value. is it?

Comment: So you know that you need to use a `Comparator`, but don't know how to use it? Why don't you learn?

Comment: As there are three fields, you can't simply use `binarySearch`. To use `binarySearch` the list must be sorted. You can't sort a list on three fields.

Comment: I edited my code. is this correct approach? It is just a sample actually I have 25 property in bean.

Comment: How many elements will be in the list (`testList`)?

Comment: @RafiKamal I know compare but I don't know dynamic property comparision. that is why I am asking if one propert I can do 
public int compareTo(Test test) {test.getId() serach with values} } but with dyanmic propery. I have to write code static like id, name. it's so mess.

Comment: @NFE you can use a `Map` instead. Something like `Map["id"] = "123"; Map["name"] = "abc";` Then while searching, you can check if `Map[propertyName] == propertyValue`

Comment: @RafiKamal  It will have 1000 or above element. it's not fix. it fatched from database. I am not searching of database because it is very secure app. here client encrypt/decrypt data in browser. then in database it was encrypted, but at client browser, data is plain. so I have to make search  in plain data not encrypted data. so I can not make database hit.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do a bin-search with this problem. If you want to do a binary search, your elements in the collection must be sorted by the given propertyName. If it is not, you have to sort it first (with comparator for example). So you are changing a `O(n)` problem to `O(nlgn)`.

what I can think of is: java reflection API.... That is, in your `searchData` method, build the getter method (java.lang.reflect.Method) by the given property name. And invoke (`method.invoke()` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object...) ) to get the property value. And do the filtering.

You can implement it by yourself, if you don't mind to use libraries, you could take a look apache beanUtils: (getProperty() method)

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtilsBean.html#getProperty(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)

also the `Iterables.filter()` method from guava:

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter(java.lang.Iterable, com.google.common.base.Predicate)

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you can't use binary search without sorting the list first, so I will not take that into account.

I have an elegant solution to this problem using Google's [Guava libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and without resorting to reflection.

```
public static <T, V> Collection<T> filter(List<T> source, final Function<? super T, V> function, final V value) {
    return Collections2.filter(source, new Predicate<T>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(T input) {
            return value.equals(function.apply(input));
        }
    });
}
```

This function takes three parameters.

1. The list you want to filter.
2. A function which takes an element of the list, and returns the value of the property you want to filter on
3. The value you want the property to have

In order to use it before Java 8, you can write something like this:

```
static class Test {
    int id;
    String name;
    String address;

    public Test(int id, String name, String address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    //Setter and getter method of properties...

    public static final Function<Test, Integer> GetId = new Function<Test, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer apply(Test input) {
            return input.id;
        }
    };
    public static final Function<Test, String> GetName = new Function<Test, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(Test input) {
            return input.name;
        }
    };

}
```

Once you have `Test.GetId`, `Test.GetName` etc defined, using `filter` is easy and clear:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Test> t = Arrays.asList(new Test(1, "A", "B"), new Test(2, "C", "D"));
    Collection<Test> f1 = filter(t, Test.GetId, 2);
    Collection<Test> f2 = filter(t, Test.GetName, "A");
}
```

Comment: OP has a big block of "if this property, call getThisProperty() else if that property..." Your approach is just moving this block into the bean class right? if doing so, a `Map<String, Object>` is enough. e.g. `PropertyMap<String, Object> map` then `map.put("name",this.name);.....`

Comment: Ok but with this approach you don't have to create a map for every object, just for the sake of searching. I'd rather go with reflection if there are many classes with different properties. Or use something like Lambdaj.

Comment: the map would be in the bean class.   I wrote THIS.name